# Twitter bootstrap 3.0 menu/header in mobile version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building website with Bootstrap 3.0 and when I tested it on my iPhone I detected a problem with header.
[image]

the header - "DatJoke.com" gone to the wrong place. Can you please help me what might be a problem with it?

Here is the access to the website via Git https://github.com/ummahusla/datjoke.com

Thank you in advance

Comment: Double check your mark-up and compare it with the bootstrap docs, but honestly I've been having a lot of issues like this with bootstrap 3.0. It's going to be hard for anyone to figure out how to help you if you don't post any source code or explain what you've tried and failed to do to fix the problem.

Comment: I posted all code from the website. I absolutely run out of ideas what it can be, and what can be solution. I tried to google it, but still unsuccessfully. I was hoping that here, someone already had this issue.

Comment: Edvin,  you need to learn to use Safari's developer tools in iOS simulator to debug your css to see why the element is not styled how you are expecting it.

Or take the source and recreate it, simplified, in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as the mobile browser is simply too small to fit that header. You need to remember that bootstrap is responsive and will adapt to the best "view" for devices based on their screen size. You have three options:

1. Remove the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` from the `head` - it might work on some phones as without this tag they are no longer forced to display the mobile version.
2. Compile a non-responsive version of bootstrap
3. Do the following and have a navbar like the one on http://getbootstrap.com and follow the following instructions:

First of all, you need to include `bootstrap.js` for the responsive navbar.
Secondly, your navbar needs to be in this format:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><!-- Your site name --></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <!-- Nav elements -->
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

So for you example, it should be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DatJoke.com</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="addjoke.html">Add joke</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
```